# How do I execute a command from a variable and capture its output in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, command-line

I would like to set a variable to a command, then execute it and capture the output in another variable. I want to have both the command, and the output, for logging purposes.

For running `ls`, I was thinking the following should work:

```
command="ls"; out=$(command); echo $out
```

However, when I run it, the output is empty, which means that `ls` never got executed. So, how can I execute it and capture the output?

The reason is that I want to make it easier to change the command in a single place, instead of everywhere it is used, if it ever needs changing to `ls -l` for example.

Doing it as `command="ls"; out=$(ls); echo $out` works, but it needs changing in 2 places if I want to add flags: `command="ls -l"; out=$(ls -l); echo $out`, which makes it prone to errors and harder to work with.

As a side note, what I'm trying to do is more complex than this example, it uses the command in multiple places

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- _Don't_ put commands in (simple string-type) variables; the linked FAQ provides alternatives (such as arrays).

Comment: Also, note that you mean `out=$($command)` so you're evaluating the variable `$command`, not running the command named `command` (and yes, there _is_ a shell built-in command named `command`) -- but again, don't do any of that for the reasons the FAQ lists.

Comment: The other alternative listed in the FAQ is functions, as in: `mycommand() { ls -l; }; out=$(mycommand); echo "$out"` (note use of `mycommand` to avoid overriding the built-in command `command`).

Comment: Oh, that's very helpful. `out=$($command)` seems like the best fit for what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: _Please_ do read [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) so you understand how and when `out=$($command)` fails. (An alternative is `out=$(eval "$command")`, but that's subject to security issues as discussed in [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)). There's usually a way to make the good-practice approaches work, but we can't go into the details unless we know why they _look_ like they won't work for you on first glance.

Comment: For example, if the reason you think you can't use an array is the `>outfile` in `yourCommand "with arguments" >outfile` needing to be processed as syntax, creating a function `stdoutToFile() { local _fn; _fn=$1; shift; "$@" >"$1"; }` lets one use `stdoutToFile outfile yourCommand "with arguments"`, which fits into an array nicely.

Comment: Cool way for handling redirection. For my use case I don't care for redirection (so `out=$($command)` is perfect), but it's good to know for future reference!

Comment: Did you read the FAQ? Redirection is not close to the only thing that won't work: You can't use filenames with spaces, you can't use any command that requires quoting or escaping or pipes, etc. And I don't see what it is you _gain_ by sticking with a string instead of an array; you're creating restrictions for yourself with no compensating benefit.

Comment: I have read it but not fully understood it. Some of the features still go over my head. However, I was just experimenting with an array holding the arguments and it works perfectly for what I needed here. I finally can log and execute commands in an easy to edit way for my one-liner :)